# NotificationCenter - show and hide splash

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

MainViewControler:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        // register  notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.StartUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("updating.salestool"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func StartUpdatingSplash() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        EZLoadingActivity.show("LoadingMessage4".localized(), disableUI: true)
    }
    print("##### NOTIFICATION STEP: 1")
}

@objc func FinishUpdatingSplash() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        EZLoadingActivity.hide()
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("updating.salestool"), object: nil)
    print("##### NOTIFICATION STEP: 2")
}
```

and Config.swift:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("updating.salestool"), object: nil)

let dispatchImagesGroup = DispatchGroup()
                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: FileFolders.GET_PHOTO.rawValue, parametr: FileFolders.GET_PHOTO.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: FileFolders.GET_INSPIRATION_PHOTO.rawValue , parametr: FileFolders.GET_INSPIRATION_PHOTO.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: FileFolders.GET_PACKSHOT.rawValue , parametr: FileFolders.GET_PACKSHOT.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }


                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: (AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/" + FileFolders.GET_TIPS_SLIDES.rawValue, parametr: FileFolders.GET_TIPS_SLIDES.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: (AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/" + FileFolders.GET_LEAFLETS_SLIDES.rawValue, parametr: FileFolders.GET_LEAFLETS_SLIDES.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadImages(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: (AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/" + FileFolders.GET_CONCEPTS_SLIDES.rawValue, parametr: FileFolders.GET_CONCEPTS_SLIDES.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.enter()
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.downloadLeafletsPDF(toDownloads: jsonData, savedURL: (AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/" + FileFolders.GET_LEAFLETS_PDF.rawValue)
                    dispatchImagesGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchImagesGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.FinishUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("updating.salestool.aviko.qbmobile.com"), object: nil)
            }
```

StartUpdatingSplash - runs the splash.

Function downloadImages - runs the thread for downloading photos from the internet.
The application after launch displays splash (EZLoadingActivity) and then downloads the photos.

I would like to hide EZLoadingActivity (EZLoadingActivity.hide) after finishing all these threads used to download photos, for example by running the FinishUpdatingSplash () function. How can I do this?

My notificationcenter correctly displays the splash - I have a problem just hide it

Answer (score 0):

Perform your hiding task in the main async queue.

Answer (score 0):

Is Function downloadImages in class MainViewControler?

If it's true, you can call FinishUpdatingSplash directly:

```
    dispatchImagesGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            self.FinishUpdatingSplash()
        }
```

If it's false, post notification after all download tasks finished.

```
    dispatchImagesGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil
        }
```

and you need to add observer for this notification in MainViewControler as you do for StartUpdatingSplash:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    // register  notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.StartUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("updating.salestool.aviko.qbmobile.com"), object: nil)

    //new code 

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewControler.StartUpdatingSplash), name: NSNotification.Name("FinishUpdatingSplashNotificationName"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code.
At the moment a splash is displayed and hides. The problem is that even though the splash has been hidden - the files continue to download (ie the splash should still be visible)